# Android event logging

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am looking for ward to log some events fired inside an activity such as onClick, editTextChanged, onTouch without any extra effort from the programmer by providing him a library. Are there any ways of doing it without requiring him to put some annotations inside his event handlers? For example I can create a Super activity and tell him to extend it. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you have to implement them manuelly in one class.

Answer (score -1):

I got this idea from the Mobile Cloud computing class at Coursera. Every activity in the sample code provided by that class extended this:

```
/**
 * This abstract class extends the Activity class and overrides lifecycle
 * callbacks for logging various lifecycle events.
 */
public abstract class LifecycleLoggingActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Debugging tag used by the Android logger.
 */
protected final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

/**
 * Hook method called when a new instance of Activity is created. One time
 * initialization code should go here e.g. UI layout, some class scope
 * variable initialization. if finish() is called from onCreate no other
 * lifecycle callbacks are called except for onDestroy().
 * 
 * @param savedInstanceState
 *            object that contains saved state information.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call super class for necessary
    // initialization/implementation.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // The activity is being re-created. Use the
        // savedInstanceState bundle for initializations either
        // during onCreate or onRestoreInstanceState().
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(): activity re-created");

    } else {
        // Activity is being created anew. No prior saved
        // instance state information available in Bundle object.
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(): activity created anew");
    }

}

/**
 * Hook method called after onCreate() or after onRestart() (when the
 * activity is being restarted from stopped state). Should re-acquire
 * resources relinquished when activity was stopped (onStop()) or acquire
 * those resources for the first time after onCreate().
 */
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // Always call super class for necessary
    // initialization/implementation.
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() - the activity is about to become visible");
}

/**
 * Hook method called after onRestoreStateInstance(Bundle) only if there is
 * a prior saved instance state in Bundle object. onResume() is called
 * immediately after onStart(). onResume() is called when user resumes
 * activity from paused state (onPause()) User can begin interacting with
 * activity. Place to start animations, acquire exclusive resources, such as
 * the camera.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // Always call super class for necessary
    // initialization/implementation and then log which lifecycle
    // hook method is being called.
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG,
            "onResume() - the activity has become visible (it is now \"resumed\")");
}

/**
 * Hook method called when an Activity loses focus but is still visible in
 * background. May be followed by onStop() or onResume(). Delegate more CPU
 * intensive operation to onStop for seamless transition to next activity.
 * Save persistent state (onSaveInstanceState()) in case app is killed.
 * Often used to release exclusive resources.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Always call super class for necessary
    // initialization/implementation and then log which lifecycle
    // hook method is being called.
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG,
            "onPause() - another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be \"paused\")");
}

/**
 * Called when Activity is no longer visible. Release resources that may
 * cause memory leak. Save instance state (onSaveInstanceState()) in case
 * activity is killed.
 */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Always call super class for necessary
    // initialization/implementation and then log which lifecycle
    // hook method is being called.
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG,
            "onStop() - the activity is no longer visible (it is now \"stopped\")");
}

/**
 * Hook method called when user restarts a stopped activity. Is followed by
 * a call to onStart() and onResume().
 */
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // Always call super class for necessary
    // initialization/implementation and then log which lifecycle
    // hook method is being called.
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestart() - the activity is about to be restarted()");
}

/**
 * Hook method that gives a final chance to release resources and stop
 * spawned threads. onDestroy() may not always be called-when system kills
 * hosting process
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Always call super class for necessary
    // initialization/implementation and then log which lifecycle
    // hook method is being called.
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() - the activity is about to be destroyed");
}

}
```

It was developed by Vanderbilt University for the course and was part of a framework for simplifying activities. I don't have the license to hand, but it was basically that you could use it, but you could not claim in any way that your app or code was endorsed by Vanderbilt University or Coursera.

Every activity that extends this one will automatically log all of its lifecycle methods, tagged with the class name.

### Edit

To do this with methods from interfaces, as you mentioned, you would need to create an implementation of that interface that follows this same idea, and use it as a variable in your activity instead of directly implementing the interface in your activity.

Comment: Hi I am already doing this infact more to it. What I need is logging the events. I can do that with extending a particular interface but that is not a solution for this problem. For example if I need to log onCLick events the application cannot override my onClick because otherwise my code wont be executed, but if they dont override it how can they execute their own code! See the dilemma? I am looking for ways without any extra set of APIs.

Comment: For example if I extend your class and want to have my on handler onDestroy yours wont be called right?

Comment: If you override a method you can call `super.methodName()` to run the method you are overriding. With my example method, you could override `onDestroy` in your activity, and in it call `super.onDestroy()`, and my class will log that your activity is being destroyed. In fact, Android requires you to call `super` if you override lifecycle methods or it will throw an error.

Comment: Currently I am using that option. But was thinking whether I have something different that does not involve the devs. Once they attach my library and extend it the deal is done. But unfortunately so far I did not find any option.